# Algorithm complexity without loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am sorry for asking such a Dummy question but I can't seem to find the answer. I know how to calculate the complexity of an algorithm ( O() ) when there are loops'n stuff, but in this case I have difficulty wrapping my head around it. The language is C++.

Here's the code :

```
int calculate(int k, int n){ // Code C++
    int firstSequenceEnd = k-1;
    int sumAk = ((1 + (firstSequenceEnd))*(firstSequenceEnd) ) >> 1;
    return (1 << n-k)*sumAk;
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Well, how many instructions get executed?

Comment: Following @OliCharlesworth's question: in this code the number steps does not depend on the input. It does not loop, does not recurse, just a static calculation.

Comment: That is kinda my question, does 1 << n-k counts as one or n-k ?

Comment: It's two instruction independently on the size of n or k.

Comment: _"there are loops'n stuff"_  I see no loops'n stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are no loops then we are talking about `O(1)`.

Comment: This is overly-simplistic; recursive code will generally be greater than O(1) for example, even without loops.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I agree with your comment, But there is no recursion on his example. And a recursion will be transferred (on machine code ) to loop (based on the stack but still - a loop)